# matrix polygon of a hexagon?

Tags: matrix, polygon

I need to create a hexagon shape but am not able to actually calculate the matrix points by myself. I have a example for a triangle:

```
triangle.drawPolygon([
            -32, 64,             //First point
        32, 64,              //Second point
        0, 0                 //Third point
    ]);
```

Comment: Any set of 6 points forms a hexagon :)
If you need a **regular** hexagon, you may calculate each point using the known angle between the faces and the position of the previous point

Comment: ah yea you're right. But I surely want those nice "regular" hexagons ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following website!

[Polygon matrix coords calculator](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolycalc.html)